SN75161B logic symbol
I'm trying to control an ATE with custom hardware. It's mandatory to use GPIB. For this purpose i chose two IC's SN75161B and SN75160B.

Now i'm curious about what these 1's, 2's and 3's represent/mean. I honestly have no clue and googling didn't help me either.

it possibly pairs the EN terms with the pins ... have you reviewed the IEEE Std 91-1984 document?

@jsotola thank you for your reply! Untill today i was not familiar with IEEE Std 91-1984.

you provided the document name

@jsotola just saw that this document was mentioned in the screenshot i have provided. Will take a better look next time before asking a question! Thanks once again.

TI's Overview of IEEE Standard 91-1984 gives an explanation, but you have to understand the function table.
The symbol represents a simplification of the function table.  I wouldn't hold a great deal of emphasis on it.  Since it adds to the complexity of operations.  G1 and EN2 will have actually function names, which will be tied into the documentation.  This symbol is in accordance with IEEE Std 91-1984 and IEC Publication 617-12.  Standardize symbol to facilitate basic functionality.
As jstola states, the numbers pair with Enable pins.  1 = EN1.

10 Sequence of Output Labels
If an output has a number of different labels, regardless of whether they are identifying numbers of affecting inputs or outputs or not, these labels are shown in the following order:

If the postponed output symbol has to be shown, this comes first, if necessary, preceded by the indications of the inputs to which it must be applied
Followed by the labels indicating modifications of the internal logic state of the output, such that the left-to-right order of these labels corresponds with the order in which their effects must be applied
Followed by the label indicating the effect of the output on inputs and other outputs of the element.



▽ =  three state output.  1,2 means we have to have G1, then the state of EN2 determines direction of buffer.  EN2=0, transmitter, EN2=1, receiver.
SN75161B Truth Table.

ATN is a receiver if DC (EN1) is 1, and transmitter for DC = 0.
ATN comes from protocol to make EN3.  EN2 is TE.
The SN75162B logic symbol has a 6, which is not truly explained, but I'd concentrate on the truth table.  The problem with any standard is what happens when you break the standard.

I think the IEEE logic symbols were designed to confuse the user.
The logic diagram shown to the right of the IEEE symbol in the datasheet may be easier to understand as it uses more conventional schematic symbols.

the logic gates were introduced later as part of IEEE std. 91/91a-1991

I would agree, but it is an attempt to integrate basic truth table functionality into the schematic symbol,  which would aid trouble-shooting without understanding the fundamental logic.
